# Error in Code first Seed method - Cannot update a timestamp column

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I am trying to run the seed method to create/update values in a table (config values). Initial run was successful and it created the "TestSeed" record. But the updates are throwing the following error.

Here is my Seed method,

```
 context.SystemValues.AddOrUpdate(
            sv => sv.Name,
            new SystemValue { Name = "TESTSEED", Description = "Seed test1.",    CreatedBy = "Sys", CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow, Value = "TESTSEED", ModifiedBy = "Sys", ModifiedOn = DateTime.UtcNow }
            );
        context.SaveChanges();
```

And the AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false

System values class,

```
public partial class SystemValue
{
    public int SystemValueId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

Error in Update-Database,

> PM> Update-Database
>   Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
>   No pending explicit migrations.
>   Running Seed method.
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: **Cannot update a timestamp column**.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)

Why this update does not work? Am I missing something?

**Edit**

One thing I noticed is that the RowVersion field is not Nullable. Can I make it nullable from code-first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell EF that this is a `timestamp` / `rowversion` column so that it won't try to update it. You do this by adding the `[Timestamp]` attribute on that column:

```
public partial class SystemValue
{
    public int SystemValueId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

The `TIMESTAMP` / `ROWVERSION` column in SQL Server is a special column that only SQL Server internally can update - you as a database programmer can only read it out. It keeps track of the row's version, e.g. when you read a row, you can make a note of its version, and when you go write it again, you can check to see whether the row has been modified since you've read it (then that row version column would have a different value than what you read)

Answer (score 0):

Marc_S is correct. But there is a small thing you need to consider when applying this change. If you add "TimeStamp" attribute to the existing Version field, and when I run the update-database, it gives another error - "Cannot update" Version data type I had to first delete the existing Version. Therefore you need to remove this first.

Step 1 - Delete the existing Version field, Add a new migration and do a Update-Database.

Step 2 - Add version field with "TimeStamp" and do the Migration and update-database.

The issue that I mentioned can happen if you are converting an EF Database First into EF Code First. I missed testing this System Values class in the migration process when I did that initially.